# Enviar FORM con input files vacíos PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Que tal buen día a todos. Alguna recomendación o apoyo.

Tengo un formulario en el cual tengo un tabla que se agrega datos por filas , cada fila se puede o no agregar un archivo PDF (como en la imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En JavaScript leo la tabla con los datos y el input files:

```
for (var index = 0; index < detalle.length; index++) {

 //...
 precioUnitario = detalle[index].cells[6].children[0].value.replace(/,/g, ''),
 iva = detalle[index].cells[7].children[0].value,
 precioIva = detalle[index].cells[8].children[0].value.replace(/,/g, ''),
 precioIsh = detalle[index].cells[9].children[0].value.replace(/,/g, ''),
 file = detalle[index].cells[10].children[0],
 documento = file.files.length === 0 ? 'null' : file.files[0];



 conceptos.push([precioUnitario, iva, precioIva, precioIsh]);
 formData.append('documentos[]', documento);


}
```

Y envío mi formData en un XMLHttpRequest:

```
xhr.send(formData);
```

Tengo en PHP donde voy recorriendo los datos:

```
 foreach ($detalle as $item) {

$precioUnitario = $item[7];
$iva = !empty($item[8]) ? $item[8] : 'NULL';
$precioIva = !empty($item[9]) ? $item[9] : 'NULL';
$precioIsh = !empty($item[10]) ? $item[10] : 'NULL';

 if (!empty($_FILES['documentos']['name'][$index])) {

                $file_name = $_FILES["documentos"]["name"][$index];
                $file_tmp = $_FILES["documentos"]["tmp_name"][$index];

                $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                $documento = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "_"
                    . date('dmY-His', time()) . "." . $ext;

                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $this->path_data . "\\ruta\\" . $documento);

               
            }

    $query .= "INSERT INTO Datos(precio, iva, precioIva, precioISH, documento) values(
                       $precioUnitario ,$iva,$precioIva , $precioIsh, $documento)";
}
```

El detalle es que en PHP al leer el array **documentos** solo me lee el archivo de la **fila 3**, y en cada recorrido voy guardando el registro de cada fila y si existe un archivo , pero como **la fila 0 y 1** están vacías toma el **archivo fila 3** como si fuera la **posición 0** y guarda el datos en la fila 0.

Array recibido:

> ```
> Array (
>    
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => 57.pdf
>             [type] => image/pdf
>             [tmp_name] => /tmp/php9bNI8F
>             [error] => 0
>             [size] => 61429
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Alguna forma de hacer que me respete los valores vacíos por posición algo así como:

> ```
> Array (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>           
>         )
>
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>             [name] =>  57.pdf
>             [type] => image/pdf
>             [tmp_name] => /tmp/php9bNI8F
>             [error] => 0
>             [size] => 61429
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Comment: Pista, Algo vacío no es lo mismo que... `""` o que `NULL`

Comment: Si entiendo , pero aun así el $_FILES['documentos'] solo muestra los documentos cargados.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el resultado de `var_dump($_FILES['documentos']);` eso nos puede dar una pista para manejar los archivos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que veo en tu código es cuando asignar el archivo a la variable documentos.

```
documento = file.files.length === 0 ? 'null' : file.files[0];
```

Cuando se realiza el ciclo for, este se reescribe por el siguiente, lo que puedes hacer es asignarla como un arreglo y poder así guardar los resultados.

Nota: no declares la variable documentos adentro del ciclo for.

```
documento = [];
documento.push(file.files.length === 0 ? 'null' : file.files[0]);
```

El `FormData` no lo pongas en el for, déjalo afuera y realizar el recorrido al momento de enviarlo

```
documento.forEach(file => {
   formData.append('documentos[]', file);
});
```

ya lo envías normalmente por ajax.

Comment: Gracias amigo, El problema realizo la acción $_FILES["documentos"][index] los vacíos no los lee. Solamente los cargados. Y cada fila puede o no agregar un PDF.